# How does MEF determine the order of its imports?

Tags: c#, mef

MEF allows you to import multiple parts via the use of the `ImportMany` attribute. How does it determine the order in which it retrieves the relevant exports and adds them to the enumerable you are populating? For example, how would I import multiple IRules that had to fire in a particular order? The only way I can think of is to have an OrderValue property in IRule and sort manually:

```
public class Engine
{
  [ImportMany]
  public IEnumerable<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

  public void Run()
  {
    // ...
    // Initialise MEF
    // ...

    //
    // Do I need to manually order Rules here?
    //

    foreach (IRule rule in Rules)
    {
      // Must execute in a specific order
      rule.Execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your assumption is correct - it seems a little outside of the problem MEF is intended to solve.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default MEF does not guarantee any order of the exports that get imported. However in MEF you can do some ordering by using some metadata and a custom collection. For example you can do something like:

```
public interface IRule { }

[Export(typeof(IRule))]
[ExportMetadata("Order", 1)]
public class Rule1 : IRule { }

[Export(typeof(IRule))]
[ExportMetadata("Order", 2)]
public class Rule2 : IRule { }

public interface IOrderMetadata
{
    [DefaultValue(Int32.MaxValue)]
    int Order { get; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public Engine()
    {
        Rules = new OrderingCollection<IRule, IOrderMetadata>(
                           lazyRule => lazyRule.Metadata.Order);
    }

    [ImportMany]
    public OrderingCollection<IRule, IOrderMetadata> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will have a set of rules that are ordered by the metadata. You can find the OrderingCollection sample at http://codepaste.net/ktdgoh.

Comment: It seems that the OrderingCollection sample is no longer available.

Comment: I think a derivative of `OrderingCollection` can be found in Sony Authoring Tools Framework source, [here](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/master/Framework/Atf.Gui/Collections/AdaptingCollection.cs).

Comment: I notice that codepaste is gone, so I've places it here for whoever needs it: https://gist.github.com/mika76/8cab4c16e420da4fe6e069071415ca70

Answer (score 6):

The best way to achieve this ordering in MEF is to utilize our metadata facilities. You can attach your own metadata to exports which you can use for ordering and filtering. Metadata also allows you to delay instantiation of parts until they are actually needed. Additionally you can create custom Export attributes which provide a nice clean way of providing the metadata.

Check this link for information on how to define metadata and custom exports: [link text](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide)

You may also find [this](http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=64387) thread on our MEF forums useful. Within you'll find a discussion about an AdaptingCollection approach which lets you use a custom collection which applies a metadata filter / order.

HTH
Glenn

Comment: Thanks Glenn, in the end I took a different approach but I'll certainly bear this in mind for next time. I would accept your answer but as Wes got in just before with a similar response I think it's probably fairer to accept his.

Comment: It's ok, Wes based his version on mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could have the rules import each other in order (using the Decorator pattern), but then each rule will need to know about the specific rule that precedes it, which probably isn't what you want.

MEF is there to help you discover the parts, what you do with them afterwards is up to you. If you want to sort the parts then go ahead, there's nothing wrong with that!

Comment: To me it seems more efficient to insert elements into a sorted list than generate a list and then sort