# How to define the order with ImportMany attribute?

Tags: .net, mef

I am just getting into MEF and was wondering how you could define the order of collection exported with [ImportMany]?

What I mean here is if I had two classes (Class1, Class2) that implement the interface IService and each of the implementations are in two different libraries (although they could be in the same), I want the Class2 instance to be created before the Class1 instance in the IEnumerable collection defined by the ImportMany attribute. So it is like a pipeline of functionality where Class2 calls are made before Class1 calls.

Also, I have an another Class (Class3 which also implements IService) in another library, which I want introduced later on (i.e. some logging utility), how do I make this the 3rd instance in the ImportMany collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll could 'Lazy' load them first and then check an order attribute as you add them to a collection.

Or check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770297/how-does-mef-determine-the-order-of-its-imports/1772554#1772554) which has an example of exacly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am still getting to grips with MEF.

Answer (score 4):

From a MEF perspective I think you're approaching this problem from the wrong angle.  MEF encourages a separation between interface and implementation.  To have the consumer dictate the order of the implementations, it forces it to understand the implementation.

The approach taken by Visual Studio is a bit different.  It uses the [OrderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.orderattribute.aspx), usually in combination with the [NameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.nameattribute.aspx)  to let the implementors specify an order.  The consumer can then sort the implementors of an `ImportMany` using a combination of names and order without understanding the underlying implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Still a bit confused, as far as the client is concerned, he will have a collection of IService[] which I saw as a pipe line of functionality (we still have separation between interface and implementation here). The consumer/client does not dictate the order, it is what is available and the order they are in the IService[] collection. Now if we want a service to be run before another (in the pipeline), how do we  do this? Sorry, if I have not understood your answer (as I clearly haven't)